# R shiny rhandsontable getting error hot_to_r function

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, rhandsontable

I am using rhandontable with checkboxes to capture the row selections. In the observeEvent, I use hot_to_r to capture the input table. But I get this error:

```
 Called from: observe()
Browse[1]> hot_to_r(input$hot)
Error in as(d[[i]], colClasses[i]) : 
  no method or default for coercing “character” to “NA”
```

Here is my shiny code:

library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

```
ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(wellPanel(
    rHandsontableOutput("hot"),
    actionButton(inputId="enter",label="enter")
  ))
))





server=function(input,output){



  output$hot=renderRHandsontable({
    cs_list <- structure(list(id = c(2200L, 2199L, 2198L, 2197L, 2196L, 2194L,
                                     2192L, 2191L, 2190L, 2182L), name = LETTERS[1:10], createdDate = structure(c(1686085982.446, 1686083874.989,
                                                                  1686081629.669, 1686076846.466, 1686067053.29, 1686064540.23,
                                                                  1686007128.569, 1686006010.05, 1686005209.098, 1685991901.098
                                     ), tzone = "America/Chicago", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
                              createdBy = c("troggenkamp", "troggenkamp", "troggenkamp",
                                            "troggenkamp", "ushrestha", "troggenkamp", "troggenkamp",
                                            "troggenkamp", "troggenkamp", "troggenkamp"), bool = c(FALSE,
                                                                                                   FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
                                            )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

    rhandsontable(cs_list, readOnly = FALSE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$enter, {
    DF=hot_to_r(input$hot)
    print(DF)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with the datetime column. You can do:

```r
    cs_list$createdDate <- format(cs_list$createdDate)
    rhandsontable(cs_list)
```